# Url.Action to Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code om my View. And this is work good.

```
   ... onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Plan", "Care", new {Area = "HomeC"})'"><img src="~/Content/images/dash/Care.PNG"
```

How Can I do the same code with Html.Raw?
I tried this

```
  grid.Column(columnName: "Name", header: "", format: @<text>@(item.ListStatus == 1 ? Html.Raw("<button class='btn btn-default btn-plan' title='Care' onclick='location.href = " + "'" + Url.Action("Plan", "Care", new {Area = "HomeC"}) + "''>" +
                                                                        "<img src='/Content/images/dash/Care.PNG' class='img-plan' data-interlocutorid=" + item.UserId + " " +  "data-interlocutorname=" + item.Name + " " + ">" + 
                                                                    "</button>") : Html.Raw(""))
                                                                 </text>),
```

With image all good, but link doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I edit my code. Look at please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 onclick=" + "location.href=" + "'" + Url.Action("Plan", "Care", new {Area = "HomeC"}) + "'" + ">"
```

This is work good.

Answer (score 0):

Change the single-quotes around your Url.Action(...) to double-quotes instead.

That is, change this portion:

```
onclick='location.href = " + "'" + Url.Action("Plan", "Care", new {Area = "HomeC"}) + "''
```

to this:

```
onclick='location.href = " + "\"" + Url.Action("Plan", "Care", new {Area = "HomeC"}) + "\"'
```

This will change the rendered output from:

```
onclick='location.href = '/Care/Plan?Area=HomeC''
```

to:

```
onclick='location.href = "/Care/Plan?Area=HomeC"'
```